# Windows не пропускает BlockInput() C++

Tags: c++

При написании макроса под Windows на C++ возникает необходимость временно отключить мышь и клавиатуру, что бы пользователь не навредил нормальной работе. Есть функция BlockInput() которая в принципе всем устраивает. Проблема в том, что если у пользователя нет прав администратора эта функция не работает.

1. Есть ли какой-то более мягкий способ заставить систему игнорировать ввод с клавиатуры и мыши?
2. Или может быть можно заставить систему не блокировать эту функцию путем каких-либо манипуляций с реестром? Саму программу запускать под админом не вариант.
   Спасибо!

Comment: Есть ещё `EnableWindow()` - может доступна юзеру, нужно проверить.

Comment: EnableWindow() не так удобен как BlockInput(), но в целом помогло.
Спасибо.

Comment: Если при помощи EnableWindow() заблокировать мышь или клавиатуру для конкретного окна то в таком случае блокируются и команды макроса. Каждый раз для эмуляции нажатия макросом кнопки мыши или клавиатуры необходимо включать EnableWindow(). Что опять приводит к тому, что пользователь случайным движением мыши может испортить работу макроса. Как все же проэмулировать движения мыши и клавиатуры не отключая EnableWindow()?